# Display a colorbar without associated image map

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have matplotlib figure that displays an image, histogram and a colobar under the histogram, generated by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

image = imageio.imread('imageio:camera.png')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(8,4))
divider = make_axes_locatable(axes[1])
cbar_ax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size='15%', pad=0.02)

im = axes[0].imshow(image,cmap='gray')
values, bins, patches = axes[1].hist(image.ravel(), 255, color='#cccccc', density=True)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, orientation='horizontal')

fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)

plt.show()
```

This code generates exactly this image below

[image: image histogram and colorbar]

Since it's a recurrent image (I'm studying the histogram), I would like to create a figure just displaying the histogram and the associated colorbar below it.

But to display a colorbar is mandatory provides a `image_map` as argument and I need to call `ax.imshow()` to have a image_map. The exact output I want is something like

[image: histogram and colobar]

And I don't know how to achieve that.

Of course I could edit my images in some editor (as I did), but this isn't acceptable, since every update takes me a huge effort editing many image.

Comment: From your last question you might have learned that specifying the number of bins is not useful because it assumes pure black (0) and pure white (255) to be part of your image - which is not necessarily the case. So you'd rather specify the bins themselves and then plot an image of the color gradient itself as "colorbar".

Comment: Nice memory, but I want to fix 0 and 255 as part of my analysis. Those are invariants. Anyway in this case, the limits of camera man are [0, 255].

Comment: Indeed, that's why `bins=255` is wrong, because you may end up with 255 bins between 10 and 149 if the image is rather dark.

Comment: it's rather `bins=range(0,256)`.

Comment: You're right. I can solve that using `np.bincount(.., minlength=255)`

Comment: It would need to be `bins=range(0,257)` or `np.bincount(.., minlength=256)`

Comment: Yes. about `bincount`. It was a mistake, therefore you're right. But for `bins=...` I think that is `range(0,256)` total of 256 elements, 0 to 255 included.

Comment: `bins` denotes the edges. So if the last bin goes from 254 to 255 it will include those two numbers. However, 255 should of course get its own bin and therefore the last bin edge needs to be 256. This is achieved with `bins=range(0,257)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest correct again. `n=255; x=np.arange(n+1); v, b, _ = plt.hist(x, bins=np.arange(n+2))`; otherwise, if `n+1` is used in `bins` range it counts `2` in last bin.